# Which version jfreechart and jcommon jar files should I use for JDK 1.6

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am working on one web application with following software specification

jdk 1.6
netbeans 6.8
postgres 9.0.x..

Which version of jfreechart and jcommon jar files should I use?Please help me.Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are my Maven dependencies for jfreechart and jcommon. they work fine with 1.6:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfree.chart</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfree.chart</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Not saying that only these will work but these are live and running for months for me.

Comment: thank you..But I am not using maven.Then which version should I use?

Comment: The versions are the ones in the <version> tags. Ignore the rest around them.

1.0.15 for jcommon and 1.0.12 for jfreechart.

Answer (score 1):

JFreeChart needs JDK 1.3, so you´ll be fine using the most recent versions.

Comment: thank you..I will follow with jcommon 1.0.18 and jfreechart 1.0.14.Is that okay with jdk 1.6

Comment: Quote from the project site :"
Requirements

JFreeChart requires the Java 2 platform (JDK version 1.3 or later). Note that JFreeChart is a class library for use by developers, not an end user application."